# Wave velocity dependence on frequency

Tags: waves

Is the velocity of a wave dependent or independent of its frequency? I cannot figure this out on my own. I've asked friends and they do not know.

Comment: Wikipedia's [wave velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_velocity) page takes you to both group velocity and phase velocity, and the relations to frequency are in plain sight.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the so called dispersion relation of the wave.

Even then the answer is complicated, as you can define several velocities (the most commonly used ones are phase, group and signal velocity).

I assume you know the relation $c = \lambda \cdot f$. This is written more conveniently (for working with complex exponentials) as $\omega = c k$ in physics, where $k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ and $\omega = 2\pi f$. This is the dispersion relation of light, in general one can give the relation $\omega(\vec k)$. From this you can deduce the phase and group velocity by:

$$v_\text{group} = \nabla_{\vec k} \omega(\vec k)$$
$$v_\text{phase} = \frac{\omega(\vec k)}{k}$$

For light in a vacuum the velocity does not depend on the frequency (and the phase and group velocities are equal), this changes as soon as $\omega(\vec k) \not\propto k$, this is the case for many types of waves, such as surface waves on water, light waves in media.